# Simple firestore insert not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase

I am attempting a simple set operation in javascript using firebase and can't seem to do a successful insert here is my attempt so far :

```
            function registerNewRodeoUser(newUserId) {
            var username = document.getElementById("signupUsername").value

            var data = {
                "name" : username
            };

            firebase.firestore().collection("players").doc(newUserId).set(data).then(function () {
                var modal = document.getElementById("signUpModal");
                modal.style.display = "none";
                showState(StatesEnum.SPLASH);
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
            });

        }
```

and this is called by the Auth call which looks like this :

```
            function signUp() {
            var email = document.getElementById("signupEmail").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("signupPassword").value;

            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function (result) {
                registerNewRodeoUser(result.user.uid)
            }).catch(function (error) {
                // Handle Errors here.
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                // display some error modal that says wron sign up info
                showSnackBar(error.message)
            });
        }
```

I have tried putting a try catch around as well no errors just don't get a write and no break point hit in the fail block either. Thanks for the help !

After a couple attempts I have noticed everything works as expected outside of the returned then block from the auth result. How can I do a promise within a promise ?

Comment: can you console result after createuserWithEmailAndPassword to be sure you are passing any valid data? 
Also you can inspect the network request/responses in chrome console dev. Can you show any of that to help more?

Comment: The account is created in fb auth so I know that section is working correctly its just the inner chained insert that is not working :/

Comment: Can you show the entire JavaScript code, not only two snippets. Your code should work, so you probably have a problem somewhere else.